# How to limit the view of a larger HTML <canvas> "inside" its parent <div>?

Tags: html, scroll, html5-canvas

I've got a 5500 pxl wide panorama img (with usemap='#imagemap') on which I've overlain a canvas. These are parented inside a div.

Everything works as expected; the img view is restricted to the div, and can be scrolled. But the complete (wiiiide) canvas is visible in the browser window.

In addition, the canvas doesn't scroll with the div/img. I have to move it in an onscroll().

Edit: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/91y2upam/1/ showing the canvas (outlined in green) escaping from the div.

Can a canvas be kept "inside" its parent div, with restricted view, and scrolled?

If so, how so?

The CSS:

```
#divPano {
  width:  100%;
  overflow: auto;
  }
#cvsPano {
  pointer-events: none;       /* make the canvas transparent to the mouse - needed since canvas is position infront of image */
  position: absolute;
  }
```

and HTML:

```
<div name="divPano" id="divPano">
  <canvas id='cvsPano'></canvas> 
  <img  name='imgPano'  id='imgPano' usemap='#mapPano'  src='Pano/Pano0H500s.jpg' >
  </div>
```

and the overlay JS (called from onload()):

```
function cvsInit(cvs, img) {
  var x, y,  w, h;

    // get it's position and width+height
  x = img.offsetLeft;
  y = img.offsetTop;
  w = img.width;
  h = img.height;

    // place cvsPano in front of the image
  cvs.style.zIndex = 1;
  cvs.parentNode.style.zIndex = 2;    //  <- this didn't work :-(

    // position it over the image
  cvs.style.left = x+'px';
  cvs.style.top = y+'px';

    // make same size as the image
  cvs.setAttribute('width', w+'px');
  cvs.setAttribute('height', h+'px');

    // get it's context
  hdc = cvs.getContext('2d');

    // set the 'default' values for the colour/width of fill/stroke operations
  hdc.strokeStyle = '#007700';
  hdc.lineWidth = 1;

  }    //  function cvsInit()
```

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this code, I don't understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parent `position:relative` and the oversized child canvas `position:absolute`.

1. Add scrollbars with `overflow:scroll` or
2. Pan programmatically with the parent `overflow:hidden` and moving the canvas with `left:-100px`.

**Pan using scrollbars**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/canvas%20compositing.png";
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:50px; }
canvas{position:absolute; border:1px solid red;}
#parent{position:relative; overflow:scroll; width:300px; height:300px; border:2px solid blue; }
```

```html
<div id=parent>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=800 height=500></canvas>
</div>
```

**Pan programatically**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

$myslider=$('#myslider');
$myslider.attr({min:-200,max:0}).val(0);
$myslider.on('input change',function(){
  $('#canvas').css('left',parseInt($(this).val()));
});


var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/canvas%20compositing.png";
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:50px; }
canvas{position:absolute; left:0px; border:1px solid red;}
#parent{position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:300px; border:2px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=myslider type=range>
<br>
<div id=parent>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=800 height=500></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks markE, but I'm trying to get the canvas overlaid on an "image-map", and get them both to scroll together.

Comment: Sorry. that went out too early. :-)

Comment: So did that one.  Forgot about <CR>s.  The position:relative in the parent div did the trick. Nothing else needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the css, try changing the property **overflow** to something else like:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Maybe that way it will scroll with the page.